# preload webview

Tags: java, android

I have a webview and i have next previous buttons to get to the next or previous picture.
What i want to do if possible is : Can i display the first picture but the webview loads (in the background the other pictures(other URLS) so that are available in the cache when a new picture is needed. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible if you use two `Webviews` and a `ViewFlipper` to change between them.

This way while the user looks at one, the other is loading the content. And when flips(you need to implement) it will bring up instantly the loaded image.

Comment: i actually used N webviews for N pictures and a viewflipper.