# pre-load a webview on android so user doesn't have to wait for the slow loading time

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I'm making an app where the main content that te user wants to view is in the form of html pages, I'm actually porting an app over from iphone and want to reuse the pages because there are 100 of them and recreating them as android layouts would be quite time consuming. The problem is that on android the webview takes about 4-5 seconds to load the first time I open a page and a couple seconds each subsequent time.

I searched and found a similar answer but don't know if it will work for my situation([preload webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189893/preload-webview)). This answer suggests using a viewflipper with multiple webviews already loaded so when you switch between them it is instantly loaded. I don't know if that will work for me because I have 100 different pages to cache(Although I could optimize it down to about 30 max by only loading ones the user can navigate to from their current page) and because the webviews are in a different activity than the button the user clicks to view the page. i.e the user is looking at a listview with about 30 different options for pages to view, when they click a listview entry it opens the activity with the webview and I would have to wait until the user made that click to begin loading the webviews, so theres no way to shave off any loading time there.

I suppose since the listview and webview activities are the same, just a small view for the title then either the webview or the list underneath of it, I could consolidate into one activity and have the listview as well as all the webviews in the view flipper and the only thing I would lose is the transition between the listview activity and the webview one, which is not a big deal. Would this solution work? Should I really just cache up to 30 webview pages? I don't think this is a viable solution and I want to ask if anyone who is better than me with android programming has a better solution. If I could preload just one page that would be enough, although not optimal, because it only takes a couple seconds to load the 2nd 3rd 4th etc... pages.

tl:dr - webview takes 5 seconds to load the first page and a couple for each one after that. I wan't to make it instant but if that isn't possible i want to at least preload the first one(idk which html page to load until the user actually clicks an option btw, and there are 100 different options) so it doesn't take 5 seconds. Right now I'm looking at finding a way to preload/cache up to 30 pages so all the users options are already loaded but that might use to much memory. Also considering finding a way to open the activity in the background and load the webview with whatever page, doesnt matter, just to get through the initial 5 second load time.

Sorry I actually had trouble wording this well for some reason, I hope you can follow what I'm trying to do. Thanks

Oh BTW - all of the html is stored locally in my assets folder and I'm using webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/About cards.html"); etc to load the pages